# Viewpager and background thread

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Whenever I swipe in ViewPager, I have the following process

1. Create a new instance of ListView in instantiateItem.
2. Add this ListView into ViewPager.
3. Start a background thread to load data, then send a message to UI
   thread to set the loaded data to the Listview created in step 1.

My question is, if i swipe very very fast, my guess is that there would be many threads created in step 3 that is unnecessary to be run, so, how do I deal with this situation?
How do I stop those threads from running?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(MAX_SIZE)` and set MAX_SIZE to whatever you are comfortable with. After the Page gets out of this range

```
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
```

will be called. In this you can handle the thread by calling cancel and do whatever else is required for that page. This will limit the number of threads running at the same time no matter how fast you scroll through.

instantiateItem item will be called again when the user scrolls back to its range.